# Why does my bash function handle arguments as a string?

Tags: macos, bash, function, shell

I am attempting to gather my ip address and subnet bits (such as 192.168.2.17/24) to pass to fing along with a name to scan a network and create a set of output files. I wrote a working script that takes in the address/len and a job name. I ultimately want to be able to extend the shell script automatically pull the address/len so that I only need to enter the job name. I'm using a Mac, if that helps.

**fing.sh** (This works!)

```
#Create a fing profile and scan
mkdir $2
fing -n $1 -r 3 -d false --session $2/persist.fing \
-o table,html,$2/fing.html -o table,csv,$2/fing.csv \
-o table,xml,$2/fing.xml -o table,json,$2/fing.json
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

#Variables
ipaddr=ip
hexmask=netmask
testmask=255.255.252.0
#thing=0
```

The ip and netmask functions work; at least they seem to.

```
#Functions
ip()
{   
    ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'    
}

netmask()
{
    ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $4}'      
}
```

The functions, **mask2cidr** and **hex2decip** to work as individual scripts.

```
mask2cidr() {
#Source: 
#http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-cidr-calculator-646701/#post3173472
#Convert dotted decimal subnet mask to cidr format
    nbits=0
    IFS=.
    for dec in $1 ; do
        case $dec in
            255) let nbits+=8;;
            254) let nbits+=7;;
            252) let nbits+=6;;
            248) let nbits+=5;;
            240) let nbits+=4;;
            224) let nbits+=3;;
            192) let nbits+=2;;
            128) let nbits+=1;;
            0);;
            *) echo "Error: $dec is not recognised"; exit 1
        esac
    done
    echo "$nbits"
}



hex2decip()
{
#Source:
#https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/ifconfig-display-non-hex-netmasks.2834/#post-86216
#Converts hex formatted subnet to dotted decimal format
if [ ! "$1" ] ; then
        echo
        echo "$MyName - converts an IP address in hexadecimal to dotted decimal" 
        echo "Usage: $MyName <hex_address>"
        echo 
        exit 1
fi

echo $1 | sed 's/0x// ; s/../& /g' | tr [:lower:] [:upper:] | while read B1 B2 B3 B4 ; do                             
        echo "ibase=16;$B1;$B2;$B3;$B4" | bc | tr '\n' . | sed 's/\.$//'                                              
done
}
```

**ipaddr** and **hexmask** output as expected

```
${ipaddr}
${hexmask}
```

For **hex2decip**, **hexmask** seems to pass "netmask" instead of the result of the *netmask* function.

```
hex2decip $hexmask


exit 0
```

**./test.sh OUTPUT**

```
10.0.180.14
0xffffff00
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: N
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: T
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: M
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: S
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
```

Comment: Why would `$hexmask` invoke anything? You'll need to use backticks or `$()` syntax for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hexmask=netmask
```

Sets the shell variable `hexmask` to the string `netmask`. That's just how the shell works.

If you want the result of calling the shell function `netmask`, you need to use command substitution:

```
hexmask=$(netmask)
```

(after first defining the `netmask` function, of course.)

By the way,

```
ipaddr=ip
testmask=255.255.252.0
```

work the same way. `ipaddr` is set to the string `ip` and `testmask` to the string `255.255.252.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

When I change to hexmask=$(netmask), I get "./test.sh: line 5: netmask: command not found."

Comment: @somehume: You have to do that *after* you define the function `netmask`. Since you are just pasting script fragments and not a complete script, it is hard to know which fragment goes where. I thought you defined the functions before trying to invoke them.

Comment: hehe...  (procedural)

I pasted the whole thing then broke it up. That makes a lot more sense now. Thanks a bundle. I've been at this all day.